# create a list of int from list of quoted int

Tags: python-3.x, list

Maybe a bit of a dumb question here, but been puzzled about this.
How to create a list of int from a list of a single-quoted string of ints.
I tried with split and replace.

```
intList =   ['123 , 456 , 789 ,101112']
```

expected:

```
 intList  =  [ 123, 456, 789, 101112 ]
```

Please note this is different to `[ '123' , '456' ,'789' ,'101112' ]` which we could simply use a list comprehension and cast each item to int

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x = [int(s) for s in ''.join(intList).split(',')]
>>> x
[123, 456, 789, 101112]
```

OR

```
x = [int(s) for s in intList[0].split(',')]
>>> x
[123, 456, 789, 101112]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
intList =   ['123 , 456 , 789 ,101112']

intList = [
    int(j)
    for i in intList
    for j in i.split(',')
]

print(intList)
```

**Output:**

```
[123, 456, 789, 101112]
```